# How can I create a website that has a function to create and join lobbies

Tags: javascript, html

Me and my friends have been enjoying the game among us, as most of you have as well. We had a lot of free time and made a IRL version that was really fun but could be even better with the help of a program that does the following (*Before reading these I want to express that I don't need answers to every little detail but just want a direction to follow or a tool to help me achieve these functions*) .

1. **has the ability to create and and join lobbies based off a code given** (*kinda like among us*).
2. **can randomly pick 2 people out of the amount joined and assign them the imposter role**.
3. **can distribute a togglable amount of tasks per player**(*tasks being just like strings of text for those who haven't played*). Now the issue I have is I could make all these features in unity, (*except the lobby system at the moment*) but there's no good way to get everyone the app on their iPhone.

So my question is this, ***where do I go to create all these features?, especially the lobby system***. I Know I've asked a lot, but I would greatly appreciate feed back and answers to help me learn how to create a website like this. Thank you all so much for reading and I look forward to seeing responses.

Comment: [This is a good example](https://github.com/Joooop/codenames.plus) project that does most of what you want.

Answer (score 2):

For #1, what you're looking for is a web socket.  There are lots of good articles online that will explain what a web socket is in depth, but web sockets are commonly used for chatrooms or any scenario where the server wants to push updates to one or more clients.

If you're wanting to make this a web project, I'd recommend using socket.io, which you can use as a javascript library.

For #2 and 3, you can also construct the logic using javascript.  Try studying OOP (object oriented programming) - you could assign different data attributes indicating imposter or not and the togglable tasks assigned per person.

Answer (score 0):

You could use socket.io, phaser and node.js. They all look like good tools for creating a multiplayer online game